# VBA Select from dropdown in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer-9

edit: I cleaned up the source code formatting and updated my VBA code.  I'm no longer getting an error, but nothing is happening in my browser window (nothing selected, nothing clicked).

I have some VBA code that allows a user to enter information into a form in Excel.  The code takes this information and generates an address to a page on our intranet.  On that page there is a dropdown list to select export format and after a format is chosen the user can click to export the file.

The VBA code I have tried (and several variations) is below:

```
Public Sub window_Open(strLocation As String, Menubar As Boolean, height As Long, width As Long, resizable As Boolean)

With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = False
    .height = height
    .width = width
    .Menubar = Menubar
    .Visible = True
    .resizable = True
    .Navigate strLocation
End With

End Sub


    Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    Dim ProductionAddress As String
    ProductionAddress = "http://Collapsed"

    window_Open ProductionAddress, True, 800, 1000, False
        Dim ie As Object
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        ie.Navigate ProductionAddress

        While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

        ie.document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00").Value = "EXCEL"

        Set objButton = ie.document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01")
            objButton.Focus
            objButton.Click

    End Sub
```

The source code for the page I am attempting to navigate is below.
Element for selecting EXCEL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
body, frameset, form {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.PageNumberText, input, button, select, table, body, frameset {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.ToolbarExport {
    display: inline;
}
.WidgetSet {
    height: 30px;
}
.ToolBarButtonsCell {
    padding-left: 6px;
}
.MenuBarBkGnd {
    background-color: #ECE9D8;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; overflow: auto;"><form name="ReportViewerForm" id="ReportViewerForm" action="ReportViewer.aspx?%2fProduction%2fWell+Daily+Production&amp;StartDate=01%2f01%2f2015+00%3a00%3a00&amp;EndDate=07%2f21%2f2015+00%3a00%3a00&amp;WellName=Acadia&amp;rs%3aParameterLanguage=&amp;rc%3aParameters=Collapsed" method="post"><table id="ReportViewerControl" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" onclick="if (document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00') != null) document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00').ParametersController.HideActiveDropDown();" onactivate="if (document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00') != null) document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00').ParametersController.HideActiveDropDown();" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td><div class="MenuBarBkGnd"><div class="ToolBarButtonsCell"><div class="ToolbarExport WidgetSet"><table style="display: inline;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td height="28"><select name="ReportViewerControl$ctl01$ctl05$ctl00" title="Export Formats" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00" onchange="document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01').Controller.SetViewerLinkActive(document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00').selectedIndex != 0);"><option value="EXCEL">Excel</option></select></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></form></body>
</html>
```

And the source code for the export element:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.DisabledLink {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
body, frameset, form {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.PageNumberText, input, button, select, table, body, frameset {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.ToolbarExport {
    display: inline;
}
.WidgetSet {
    height: 30px;
}
.ToolBarButtonsCell {
    padding-left: 6px;
}
.MenuBarBkGnd {
    background-color: #ECE9D8;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: auto;"><form name="ReportViewerForm" id="ReportViewerForm" action="ReportViewer.aspx?%2fProduction%2fWell+Daily+Production&amp;StartDate=01%2f01%2f2015+00%3a00%3a00&amp;EndDate=07%2f21%2f2015+00%3a00%3a00&amp;WellName=Acadia&amp;rs%3aParameterLanguage=&amp;rc%3aParameters=Collapsed" method="post"><table id="ReportViewerControl" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" onclick="if (document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00') != null) document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00').ParametersController.HideActiveDropDown();" onactivate="if (document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00') != null) document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl00').ParametersController.HideActiveDropDown();" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td><div class="MenuBarBkGnd"><div class="ToolBarButtonsCell"><div class="ToolbarExport WidgetSet"><table style="display: inline;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td height="28"><a title="Export" class="DisabledLink" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01" onmouseover="this.Controller.OnLinkHover();" onmouseout="this.Controller.OnLinkNormal();" onclick="&#10;var formatDropDown = document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00');&#10;if (formatDropDown.selectedIndex == 0)&#10;return false;&#10;window.open(document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl').ClientController.m_exportUrlBase + encodeURIComponent(formatDropDown.value), '_blank')&#10;formatDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;&#10;document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01').Controller.SetViewerLinkActive(document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00').selectedIndex != 0);return false;" href="#"><script type="text/javascript">
                            document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01').Controller = new ReportViewerLink("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01", false, "ActiveLink", "DisabledLink", "", "", "");
                        </script>Export</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></form></body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does `window_Open` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually navigate to the page first in order to load the document - then use the below code:

```
ie.Document.GetElementByID("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00").Value = "EXCEL"
```

Use the option that is inside the `<option>` tag.

---

***To navigate:***

```
ie.Navigate ProductionAddress

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

ie.Document.GetElementByID("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00").Value = "EXCEL"
```

Comment: That did get rid of my error message, but it seems that still nothing is happening in my browser.  I tried to use the same code to click on "News" on a google search page for 'cat' but it didn't work either (at least no error message):

window_Open GoogleCats, True, 850, 1200, False
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ie.Navigate GoogleCats

    While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
    ie.Navigate GoogleCats
    Set objButton = ie.document.getelementbyid("gb5")
        objButton.Focus
        objButton.Click

End Sub

Comment: I apologize, I was trying to get `code` formatting to work but then I got locked out of editing.

Should I create a separate question for clicking on the Export element?

Comment: You need to explain what `window_Open` does

Comment: `window_Open` opens an Internet Explorer browser window.  I'll add the code to my question

Comment: You're actually opening 2 instances of IE. Create a public variable and assign that inside your window_Open routine instead. Or just don't use the window_Open routine at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a really hard time getting this code to work and none of the existing questions I found had clear answers, so I wanted to include the code I ended up using that worked:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
Dim ProductionAddress As String
ProductionAddress = "http://Collapsed"

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Silent = True
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ProductionAddress
End With

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

ie.document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl00").Value = "EXCEL"

Set objButton = ie.document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01")
    objButton.Focus
    objButton.Click

End Sub
```

This opened the page, selected from dropdown and clicked on an element by ID succesfully.